# Unique set from ArrayList of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, set

Hi I have an arraylist of arraylist in this format:

```
[[val1, val2],[val3,val4],[val1,val2],[val1,val5]]
```

and would like to get the unique set of arraylists:

```
[[val1, val2],[val3,val4],[val1,val5]]
```

I have tried the following:

```
Set<String> uniques = new HashSet<>();
    for (ArrayList<String> sublist : mappedEntities) {
        uniques.addAll(sublist);
    }
```

but this merges all the values of the internal arraylist together

Comment: Share your entire code. Also I think you need `Set<ArrayList<String>>` instead of `Set<String>`

Comment: As @NicholasK says, the type of `uniques` needs to be `Set<List<String>>`. The `addAll` function takes a Collection and adds each member of the collection to the Set individually -- you just want to add the entire collection as a single item.

Comment: Doesn't a `HashSet` only contain unique values like `Hashmap`?

Comment: Yes @SamzSakerz -- that's correct.

Comment: Oh, I forgot `ArrayList<String>` are unique Objects

Answer (score 2):

can use Java 8 [Collection Stream Distinct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--), 
return in `Set` datatype :

```
Set<List<String>> uniques = mappedEntities.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

if you want return in `List` :

```
List<List<String>> uniques = mappedEntities.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: While this does filter duplicates, it is an expensive way to do it, as `distinct()` creates a `HashSet` and we then create a `List`. Also we should be producing a data structure which will retain that uniqueness if we add further items to it -- we should create a Set, not a List. Finally I think an answer which uses a completely different concept is less helpful to the OP than one which explains the misconception in their current code.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply put them in a `Set` like this?

`Set<List<String>> uniques = new HashSet<>(mappedEntities);`

Your mistake is that you are flattening the inner lists and putting their items in the set separately.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you need a `Set` of *ArrayList* `Set<ArrayList<String>>`, but you are using a `Set` of *Strings* `Set<String>` instead.

Given the list :

```
List<List<String>> mappedEntities = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("val1", "val2"), 
                                                  Arrays.asList("val3", "val4"),
                                                  Arrays.asList("val1", "val2"), 
                                                  Arrays.asList("val1", "val5"));
```

All you need to do is just declare the set and use the [**`addAll()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-).

```
Set<List<String>> mySet = new HashSet<>();
mySet.addAll(mappedEntities);
```

Since a set can hold only unique values, all duplicates will not be added to the set (*No need to explicitly check this*). You can now print it out :

```
mySet.forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

Or more simply, initialize the *HashSet* using the list `mappedEntities` :

```
Set<List<String>> mySet = new HashSet<>(mappedEntities);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       List<List<String>> list= Arrays.asList(
               Arrays.asList("a","b","c"),
               Arrays.asList("a","b","c"),
               Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d"));

       Set<List<String>> uniques = new HashSet<>();
       for (List<String> sublist : list) {
          if(!uniques.contains(sublist))
          uniques.add(sublist);
       }
       System.out.println(uniques);
    }
}
```

output:

```
[[a, b, c], [a, b, c, d]]
```

Comment: Since it is a set you wouldn't explicitly need to check for duplicates. This line is not needed `if (!uniques.contains(sublist))`

Answer (score 0):

I am beginner on  STACKOVERFLOW but i to try solve your problem 
I think you want like this..

```
import java.util.*; 
public class GFG { 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        int n = 3; 

        // Here aList is an ArrayList of ArrayLists 
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String> > aList = 
                new ArrayList<ArrayList<String> >(n); 

        // Create n lists one by one and append to the 
        // master list (ArrayList of ArrayList) 
        ArrayList<String> a1 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        a1.add("1"); 
        a1.add("2"); 
        aList.add(a1); 

        ArrayList<String> a2 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        a2.add("11"); 
        a2.add("22"); 
        aList.add(a2); 

        ArrayList<String> a3 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        a3.add("1"); 
        a3.add("2"); 
        aList.add(a3); 


        Set<ArrayList<String>> uniques = new HashSet<ArrayList<String>>();
        for (ArrayList<String> sublist : aList) {
            uniques.add(sublist);
        }
        System.out.println("Your Answer"); 
        for (ArrayList<String> x : uniques) 
            System.out.println(x); 
    }


    }
```

Comment: Output: 
Your Answer

[11, 22]
[1, 2]